# My app has not stopped when i run react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I got an error when i run react-native run-android that it's not working! I run adb logcat *:E, i recieved message error: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]
Does anyone help me fix this bug! Thank very so much!

Comment: download your sdk platform tools specifically for the version that you have mentioned as compile and targeted sdk version inside build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the build and run it will go away

```
cd android 
gradlew clean
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! i have used your solution more but it's still there

Comment: Because i can't be allowed to post image here so Can you see my issue via github?
Link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27160

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fabric   or   https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a#.mgkuycqxu          =>     use this Crash Logs   library  i hope is use full for you

Comment: thank you for your support! I'm testing your solution